# Delete function gets called before button exists

Tags: javascript

I've had this issue before, essentially I'd like to keep everything my app separate i.e caching the dom, binding events, no html in javascript etc.

I have an issue where in my `bindevents` method I have a click on the delete button, however the delete button only exists once a to do has been added.

I'm there getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Because I guess I'm searching the dom for an element that doesn't exist, how do I keep the structure as it is but only search the DOM for the delete button once an item has been added?

JS

```
(function() {
    var toDo = {
        data: [],
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.toDoApp = document.getElementById('to-do-app');
            this.toDoTemplate = document.getElementById('to-do-template');
            this.addToDo = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
            this.addToDoValue = document.getElementById('add-to-do-value');
            this.deleteToDo = document.querySelector('.to-do-delete');
        },
        load: function() {
            this.toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.toDoTemplate.innerHTML);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.toDoApp.innerHTML = this.toDoTemplate(this.data);
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.addToDo.addEventListener("click", this.add.bind(this));
            this.deleteToDo.addEventListener("click", this.delete.bind(this));
        },
        add: function(e) {
            var toDoValue = this.addToDoValue.value;
            if(toDoValue) {
                var toDoObj = {
                    value: toDoValue,
                    id: Date.now()
                }
            this.data.push(toDoObj);
            }
            this.render();
        },
        delete: function() {
            console.log("delete!");
        },
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.load();
            this.render();
        }
    }

    toDo.init();
})();
```

Comment: You could put in the button and then just hide it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you may  just try to get Elements after onload:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",toDo.init.bind(toDo));
```

And you could listen at window for all clicks, then filter them:

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
 var el = evt.target;
 do {
   if(el.classList.contains("someclass")){
     somefunc.call(el);
    }
 } while ( el = el.parentElement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be `bind()`ing your event handler functions to their scope when they're defined, not when they're setup as listeners.

```
bindEvents: function() {
    this.addToDo.addEventListener("click", this.add);
    this.deleteToDo.addEventListener("click", this.delete);
},
add: function() {
    // ...
}.bind(this),
delete: function() {
    // ...
}.bind(this),
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it doesn't appear to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the deletetodo caching and event assignment from the init procedure (which is always going to be null anyway) and listen for the event when the button is added instead.