# Struggling to keep HTML and JS separate

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic to do list in Vanilla JS, I'm using Handlebars to keep the HTML & JS separate.

Everything was going fine till I came to the delete method. Because my delete button is inside my HTML and not created inside my JS I'm finding it hard to select and delete items from the array.

I thought I'd found a way around it by looping over them but the issue with this is it tries to grab the buttons on page load, and so it returns always an empty array as on page load there are no delete buttons as no to do has been added at that point.

I've also tried putting the delete method inside the add method to counter this but this also presented issues.

Simply, can someone give me an example of a working delete method that removes the relevant item from the array using splice.

Cheers

HTML

```
    <input id="add-to-do-value" type="text" placeholder="Add to do">
    <button id="add-to-do">Add</button>
    <div id="to-do-app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="to-do-template" type="text/template">
    <ul>
    {{#this}}
        <div>
            <li id={{id}}>
                {{value}}
                <button class="delete-btn" id={{id}}>Delete</button>
            </li>
        </div>
    {{/this}}
    </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

JS

```
(function() {

    // Data array to store to dos
    var data =  [];

    // Cache dom
    var toDoApp = document.getElementById('to-do-app');
    var toDoTemplate = document.getElementById('to-do-template');
    var addToDo = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
    var addToDoValue = document.getElementById('add-to-do-value');
    var toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(toDoTemplate.innerHTML);

    // Render HTML
    var render =  function() {
        toDoApp.innerHTML = toDoTemplate(data);
    }

    // Add to dos
    var add = function() {
        var toDoValue = addToDoValue.value;
        if(toDoValue) {
            var toDoObj = {
                value: toDoValue,
                id: Date.now(),
            }
        data.push(toDoObj);
        }
        render();
    }

    // Delete to dos
    var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn');
    for(i=0; i<deleteBtn.length; i++) {
        deleteBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            for(j=0; j<data.length; j++) {
                if(data[j].id == this.id) {
                    data.splice(data[j], 1);
                    render();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Bind events
    addToDo.addEventListener("click", add);

})();
```

Comment: You might need  to check the page has completed loading before running your array-building function

Comment: Note that you declare `var toDoTemplate` twice.

Comment: Ive already provided a good answer in your last question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete function gets called before button exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525398/delete-function-gets-called-before-button-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using Handlebars makes the whole thing unnecessary complex. I would suggest that you don't use `innerHTML`, but other parts of the DOM API instead to be able to easily access the elements you need. For more complex todo items, I would consider using [`<template>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Anyway, you have to bind the event listener for removing the item when you create the new item (i.e. in the `add` function):

```js
var todos = [];
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var addButton = document.querySelector('button');
var container = document.querySelector('ul');

var add = function () {
  var content = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  var id = Date.now();
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'Delete';
  button.addEventListener('click', remove.bind(null, id));
  li.appendChild(button);
  todos.push({ content, id, element: li });
  container.appendChild(li);
};

var remove = function (id) {
  var todo = todos.find(todo => todo.id === id);
  container.removeChild(todo.element);
  todos = todos.filter(t => t !== todo);
};

addButton.addEventListener('click', add);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Add to do">
<button>Add</button>
<ul></ul>
```